# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 from USB and need help

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 via a USB drive over my Windows 7, and I cannot boot into it without installing the USB. Even with USB installed, it wants me to reinstall Ubuntu every time, even though when I do that it says Ubuntu is installed and asks if I would like to install over it.

I put everything on to the USB with a program in Windows (I believe it was called Universal USB Installer). when I try to boot without a USB, it brings me to a list of boot options, but no matter which I choose, the screen says the following:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 883)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

This Product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
US5,307,459, US5,434,072, US5,732,094, US6,570,884, US6,115,776 and
US6,327,625

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.35 (06/14/10)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 typically have a hidden boot partition / Recovery Partition. Your bios will show the F9 Recovery option upon booting. The problem is where did you install the Grub boot loader. From booting from the USB you can inspect your hard drive and see all partitions. And remove them. You can probably use the whole drive. Do you use legacy 4 partition table or EFI with GPT partitioning scheme? Technical, right? Personally I went for dual boot from windows boot loader by shrinking windows partition and installing grub on new partition. This way enables windows and linux hibernation to work. But that is not the point here, you already have wiped the main windows partition, but what about the boot partition. What is the message when trying to boot without USB?